# automatically press enter key after milliseconds java

Tags: java, php, jar, key, enter

I have written a php code and built a jar file. Through php I send parameters to jar file. In jar file I basically read the parameter with scanner - nextLine.

My question is, how can I implement such a code that acts like an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to be able to continue the program? When I send the parameter, let me say after 10 milliseconds, java will press key automatically.

Thanks for any advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class can do this for you in java. Here is an [excample](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/how-to-use-robot-class-in-java.html) how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a stop character, instead of a simulated button click.
Append a special character that is normally not found in your php-generated string and let your scanner read it character by character until special char is found.

Java code:

```
boolean found = false;
String parameter = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(!found){
       String input = sc.next();
       parameter += input + "\n";
       if(input.contains('<specialchar>')
            found = true;
    }
Thread.CurrentThread().wait(10);
//here goes the code to deal with finished input
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding , check for KeyEvent with getKeyCode() or directly pass KeyCode as hardCoded after  10 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').bind("enterKey",function(e){
 //do stuff here
});
```